# Flask, how to jsonify ONLY when return to browser

Tags: python, json, flask, cherrypy

I try to build an `RESTful` api server with Flask, and create some functions that can return `JSON` format data to browser.

Now I hope to make the code more re-usable, for example:

```
@simple_page.route('/raw_data')
def raw_data():
    # to json
    pass


@simple_page.route('/score')
def score():
    data = raw_data()
    # some calculation & return the score (to json)
    pass
```

If there any way in Flask that the function `raw_data()` returns json format result `if and only if` the result will be sent back to browser? (Something like `@cherrypy.tools.json_out()` does in cherrypy)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor out producing the `raw_data()` into a *separate* function, reused by both routes:

```
def _produce_raw_data():
    return raw_data

@simple_page.route('/raw_data')
def raw_data():
    return jsonify(_produce_raw_data())


@simple_page.route('/score')
def score():
    data = _produce_raw_data()
    # some calculation & return the score (to json)
    return jsonify(calculation_results)
```

Comment: Yes, it's a solution. But when we have a certain number of functions, such kind of reuse will make the code looks like a mess.

Comment: Checking for `raw_data`'s caller will look like a mess. Writing reusable code won't. You can always move these functions to another module.